# Copy an existing folder into newly created project in Eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plug-in wherein I am trying to get input from the user through the Wizard.
After pressing the finish button in the wizard, I'm creating a project in the workspace using the `IWorkspace`, `IProject` etc. interfaces.

I want to copy an existing folder (which may further contain sub-folders and files) into the newly created project and show that in the workspace. The folder is not an Eclipse project.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **quick-and-dirty** solution would copy the existing folder (and all its contents) to the desired location underneath the project location and refresh the project afterwards.

For example:

```
IProject project = ...
IPath location = project.getLocation();
Files.copy( pathToExistingFolder, location.toFile().toPath() );
project.refreshLocal( IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null );
```

A more **appropriate** solution would traverse the existing folder and create a copy of each file and folder found therein.

To create a new file,use

```
IProject project = ...
IFile file = project.getFile( "path/relative/to/prooject" );
file.create( inputStream, IResource.NONE, null );
// or, to override and existing file (file.eists() == true):
file.setContents( inputStream, IResource.NONE, null );
```

The `inputStream` is assumed to be backed by the currently traversed file from the existing files folder.

To create a new folder, use

```
IProject project = ...
IFolder folder = project.getFolder( "path/relative/to/prooject" );
folder.create( IResource.NONE, true, null );
```

I further assume that your existing files will ultimately end up being stored in a (jared) plug-in. In this case, the latter approach is the only viable as it lets you supply the folder structure and file contents from the plug-in storage.

The [Plugin Development Environment (PDE)](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/) provides extension points and API to [manage and execute templates during project-creation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fpde%2Fui%2Ftemplates%2Fpackage-summary.html). While you certainly wouldn't want to depend on plug-ins from the PDE, you may want to have a look at the sources: https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.pde.ui/tree/master/ui/org.eclipse.pde.ui/src/org/eclipse/pde/ui/templates

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Is there any problem in implementing the quick-and dirty way? Also, Files.copy( pathToExistingFolder, location.toFile().toPath() ); gives an error that "The method copy(Path, OutputStream) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (Path, Path)"

Comment: @tejas Make sure you are using the correct `Path` - this must be `java.nio.file.Path` not `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path`.

Comment: @tejas The preferred way to access files that are managed by the workspace is though the resources API. Thereby you will avoid possible intermediate glitches in between copying the files 'behind the back' of the workspace and refreshing the workspace state.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann are you sure the first solution copies all the contents within the directory as well? Because location.toFile.toPath() gives FileAlreadyExistsException after creating and opening the project. And if I append location with "/newFolder" and then do location.toFile.toPath() then only the main directory is getting copied but the contents within it are not getting copied.

Comment: @tejas I can't really tell without seeing your code.